# Context-based gap-fill face posture-mapper GAN

Tags: ai-design, generative-adversarial-networks, generative-model, implementation, image-generation

[image]

<sub>These images are handmade, not auto-generated like they will be in production. Apologies for inaccuracies in the graph overlay.</sub>

I am trying to build an AI like that displayed in the diagram: when given a training set of images with their corresponding node maps of face/nose posture, and an image with a missing **section** (just a gap) with a node map, I would like it to reconstruct the initial image. My thoughts immediately went to GANs for this, but after some searching, the closest I could find were:

- Face recreation without context/not filling gaps, just following pose (DeepFake)
- Filling gaps in images, but with no node reference
- Filling gaps from reference drawings/mappings, but with no way to provide sample images

I would like to hear about any implementations of such an algorithm, if possible optimised for faces, and if none exists, I would like to hear of how I would go about altering the generator of the GAN to work with the context/gap-fill bit (e.g a paper which talks about this idea, but doesn't implement it). Any guidance on the NN that is best for this type of task is also appreciated.

Comment: Not come across an exact implementation of this but would recommend you check out the generator architecture of StyleGAN by NVLabs. Its a typical GAN mapping from latents to an image distribution but thought it might be helpful because they have a trained Generator on faces.

Comment: @ashenoy thanks for your comment, and apologies for not getting back: I wanted to make sure I understood the paper before giving a response. StyleGAN seems interesting, and as though it would have potential. I was wondering, would it be possible to hijack StyleGAN's discriminator to take the nodes into account? I think it would probably be easier to alter the _discriminator_, rather than telling the generator the node positions explicitly. However, this then just leaves the question of how could we make it do gap-filling? We somehow need to feed it a 'prompt' - how could this be initialised?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may want to use a [Sum Product Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3732.pdf) for this task. SPNs are the state-of-the-art approach for face completion, and there are several more [recent papers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.06155.pdf) on this topic since the original above.

Importantly, the SPN paper also covers other approaches that work well for this task. If lower-resolution results are acceptable for your task, PCA with 100 or more components works surprisingly well. If your dataset is very large, a nearest-neighbor approach can work decently too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see my comment response to @ashenoy: could you please explain how to deal with some of the issues/concerns raised there about StyleGAN in terms of SPNs?